# Erro ao alterar registro na tabela

Tags: java, mysql

Consigo alterar manualmente, porém no projeto da erro..
O Erro:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (sistema.veiculo, CONSTRAINTveiculo_ibfk_1FOREIGN KEY (fk_idassociado) REFERENCESassociado(ID_ASSOCIADO`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

tela editar:

```
public class Edit_Veiculo extends javax.swing.JFrame {

     Conexao CONEXAO = new Conexao();
    DefaultListModel MODELO;
    int Enter = 0;

     String [] Codig;


    public Edit_Veiculo() {
        initComponents();

         //tela maximizada
        this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        Lista.setVisible(false);
        //listagem
        CONEXAO.conecta();
        MostraPesquisa();

        MODELO = new DefaultListModel();
        Lista.setModel(MODELO);
    }

 private void PesquisaPlacaMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
        MostraPesquisa();
        Lista.setVisible(false);
    }                               

private void PesquisaPlacaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        Lista.setVisible(false);
        Enter = 1;
    }                                             

    private void PesquisaPlacaKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                          
        if(Enter == 0)
        ListadePesquisa();
        else
        Enter = 0;
    }                                         

    private void ListaMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
        MostraPesquisa();
        Lista.setVisible(false);
    }                       


    private void btnUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
try{
        Associado associado = new Associado();
        Veiculo veiculo = new Veiculo();
        VeiculoDao vdao = new VeiculoDao();

        veiculo.setIdveiculo(Integer.parseInt(idveiculo.getText()));

        veiculo.setPlaca(placa.getText());
        veiculo.setRenavam(renavam.getText());
        veiculo.setMarca(marca.getText());
        veiculo.setModelo(modelo.getText());
        veiculo.setChassi(chassi.getText());
        veiculo.setAno(Integer.parseInt(ano.getText()));
        veiculo.setCor(cor.getText());        


        veiculo.setAssociado(associado);

        vdao.alterarVeiculo(veiculo);
}catch (Exception ex){
     Logger.getLogger(Edit_Veiculo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao alterar." + ex);
}
    }                                       

public void ListadePesquisa(){
 try {
            CONEXAO.executaSQL("SELECT * FROM veiculo where placa like '" + PesquisaPlaca.getText() + "%' ORDER BY placa");
            MODELO.removeAllElements();
            int v = 0;
            Codig = new String[4];
            while (CONEXAO.resultset.next() & v < 4) {
                MODELO.addElement(CONEXAO.resultset.getString("placa"));

                Codig[v] = CONEXAO.resultset.getString("idveiculo");
                v++;
            }
            if (v >= 1) {
                Lista.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                Lista.setVisible(false);
            }

            ResultadoPesquisa();
        } catch (SQLException erro) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao listar dados" + erro);
        }    
}

 public void MostraPesquisa() {
        int Linha = Lista.getSelectedIndex();
        if (Linha >= 0) {
            CONEXAO.executaSQL("SELECT * FROM veiculo where idveiculo = "+Codig[Linha]+" ");
            ResultadoPesquisa();
        }

    }

 public void ResultadoPesquisa() {

        try {
            CONEXAO.resultset.first();
           //dados associado
            idveiculo.setText(CONEXAO.resultset.getString("idveiculo"));
            numcota.setText(CONEXAO.resultset.getString("fk_idassociado"));
            placa.setText(CONEXAO.resultset.getString("placa"));
            renavam.setText(CONEXAO.resultset.getString("renavam"));
            marca.setText(CONEXAO.resultset.getString("marca"));
            modelo.setText(CONEXAO.resultset.getString("modelo"));
            chassi.setText(CONEXAO.resultset.getString("chassi"));
            ano.setText(CONEXAO.resultset.getString("ano"));
            cor.setText(CONEXAO.resultset.getString("cor"));


        } catch (SQLException erro) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao pesquisar." + erro);
        }
    }

}
```

tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE `associado` (
  `ID_ASSOCIADO` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `NOME` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `CPF` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `RG` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `CELULAR` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `TELEFONE` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `DATA_NASC` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `ESTADO` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `CIDADE` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `CEP` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `ENDERECO` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `BAIRRO` varchar(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `veiculo` (
  `idveiculo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_idassociado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `placa` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `renavam` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `marca` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `modelo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `chassi` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `ano` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `cor` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `associado`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID_ASSOCIADO`);


ALTER TABLE `veiculo`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idveiculo`),
  ADD KEY `fk_idassociado` (`fk_idassociado`);

 ALTER TABLE `veiculo`
      MODIFY `idveiculo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=18;

ALTER TABLE `veiculo`
      ADD CONSTRAINT `veiculo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_idassociado`) REFERENCES `associado` (`ID_ASSOCIADO`)
      ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

método alterar:

```
public void alterarEngate(Engate eng) {
        Transaction tx = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(eng);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Alterado com sucesso!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

print da tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: parece que o problema é no mapeamento da entidade na constraint veiculo_ibfk_1FOREIGN

Comment: Considerando `Associado associado = new Associado();`. E depois `veiculo.setAssociado(associado);` a impressão que passa é que o associado do objeto `veiculo` é 0. Pode conferir isso?

Comment: o problema está no código pois consigo alterar os registros manualmente..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde,

Acho que vc poderia colocar mais do seu código. O método todo, por exemplo. Mas aparentemente vc está tentando salvar ou atualizar um registro do veículo com um registro de associado que não existe.

Primeiramente:

```
    veiculo.setAssociado(veiculo.getAssociado());
```

Não faz mt sentido o que está escrito no trecho acima. Vc está definindo o associado do veículo com o associado que o próprio veículo já possui. (?)

Voltando ao seu problema. Sugiro que vc debugue seu código, veja o ID do associado que está sendo setado no seu veículo. Com o ID, busque por ele no banco de dados para confirmar se ele realmente existe. Caso ele não exista, está resolvido o problema: A chave estrangeira (ID_ASSOCIADO) não existe na tabela de associados. Vc terá que fazer algum tratamento em relação à isso ou alterar sua lógica.

Mas tente colocar mais do seu código pro pessoal te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda mas verificar se o id existe na tabela pai foi a primeira coisa que fiz, e existe sim! vou atualizar a pergunta com os códigos..

Comment: Em que momento do código vc está definindo o associado? Pq olhando ali no código quando vc faz     veiculo.setAssociado(associado);' o valor de associado é vazio. Não foi atribuído nada à ele após a declaração Associado associado = new Associado();

Comment: Não preciso dessa linha? desculpe, sou iniciante..

Comment: Precisa sim, mas o seu objeto está vazio. Vc simplesmente criou ele. Tente colocar valores nele para que ele possa ser localizado no banco. Depois de Associado associado = new Associado(); coloque o valor do associado que está no banco e será buscado, por exemplo: associado.setID(1);

Comment: Consegui! Obrigado pela ajuda!!